# Find and convert MPEG Layer II to MPEG Layer III

Tags: terminal, applescript, mp3

I have a programme (MP3Gain Express) that sometimes can't work with files that are MPEG Layer II. I also have some files that don't work on certain devices. I have a suspicion they might also just be MPEG Layer II files. I realise my question can be broken into three parts. I hope this is not a problem - they seem pretty interrelated to me.

1. Is there any way I can detect these files en masse (e.g. search a whole directory recursively for them)?
2. Is there a command line / Applescript solution for converting them into MPEG Layer III?
3. Will 2. cause any loss of quality?

Thanks

Tardy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer II file extension is ".mp2" and layer III file extension is ".mp3".

Then it is quite easy to get list of all files in any subfolder with specific extension. For instance, to get all layer III files :

```
set Parentfolder to choose folder "Select your top folder"
tell application "Finder" to set myList to every file of entire contents of Parentfolder whose name extension is "mp3"
```

The variable myList will contain all files with extension "mp3", in any subfolder of the selected folder.

About conversion, I do not have sample of mp2 file, so I can't test, but I am quite sure that QuickTime conversion/export can be used. You may have to use QT7 with QT7 Pro extension.